# maven problem while run the mvn cmd

Tags: maven

```
C:\apache-maven-3.0.3\automated-maven-developer-setup>mvn install:install-file -
Dfile=Oracle-UCM-10gR3-v3.3.5.jar -DgroupId=oracle-ucm -DartifactId=oracle-ucm -
Dversion=10gR3-v3.3.5 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-instal
l-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.jar
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-install-plugin:2.3.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3
.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact
 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.3.1 from central (http://re
po1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: No route to host: connect
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from
central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection tim
ed out: connect
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5:36.470s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 01 03:47:56 EDT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'install' in the current project and in the p
lugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the re
positories [local (C:\Documents and Settings\CJ4Y015\.m2\repository), central (h
ttp://repo1.maven.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundF
orPrefixException
C:\apache-maven-3.0.3\automated-maven-developer-setup>
```

i have added proxy also .

```
<proxy>
  <id>myproxy</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>proxy.bbh.com</host>
  <port>8080</port>
  <username>proxyuser</username>
  <password>somepassword</password>
  <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

It just seems that you can't connect to repo1. As you added ibiblio.org in your nonProxyHosts list I think that adding *.maven.org should work.